# application crashed when i decompressing a big file(300MB) by deng.fzip.FZip in action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, zip, compression

as the title describe,i used a third-party pacakge 'deng.fzip.FZip' to decompress a big file,about 300MB,the application crashed.I found that fzip.load(url:URLRequest) function is synchronous,not asynchronous.I think the reason maybe fzip load the total data to itself,then cause the application out of memory.how to decompress a big big .zip file in action script 3.0 ? 
thx in advance!

Comment: Anyway if a zip file is 300MB, the contents are 500MB, and since Flash/AS3 is not normally allowed disk access, the only thing you have is memory. So, if there's not enough memory to decompress, just fail out of loading the zip, probably right after reading its description data (how many files, what is the total uncompressed volume).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that synchronous methods cannot execute for longer than 15 sec in Flash Player (can be longer in AIR) no matter what timeout you set in the Publish settings.

Your best bet is to open the Class that does the decompressing and in that loop make a small check:

```
// before loop
var startingTime:int = getTimer();

// inside the loop
if (getTimer() - startingTime > TIMEOUT_VARIABLE_HERE)
{
    // save the i position, break the loop, set timeout for, let's say, 30 ms and start the loop with i = your saved i when breaking out of the loop.
}
```

It's not a fancy solution that fixes your problem in one second, but it's a really good, robust way to fix the actual problem.

Not sure if that's related, but a small note: officially Flash Player supports file's no larger than 100 MB.
However I've seen myself some flash games (in alpha testing) that consumed over 2GB of memory and still ran well.

Comment: Memory consumption does nothing with file size. I've got me a procedural generator that ate a lot of memory, but weighed 10 kilobytes. Also this restriction is for SWF, not for anything loaded by the SWF.